# IndexError: string index out of range 2018 python 3

Tags: python, string, recursion, indexing, index-error

This code basically is mirroring the string you input. I am getting

```
Type something please: Hey Hello                                                                                                                                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                      
  File "Week3Basic1.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                                                                           
    mirror(input("Type something please: "))                                                                                                                                            
  File "Week3Basic1.py", line 9, in mirror                                                                                                                                              
    result = last+  mirror(middle) + first                                                                                                                                              
  File "Week3Basic1.py", line 9, in mirror                                                                                                                                              
    result = last+  mirror(middle) + first                                                                                                                                              
  File "Week3Basic1.py", line 9, in mirror                                                                                                                                              
    result = last+  mirror(middle) + first                                                                                                                                              
  File "Week3Basic1.py", line 4, in mirror                                                                                                                                              
    first= string[0]                                                                                                                                                                    
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Code:

```
def mirror(string):

      first= string[0]
      middle= string[1:-2]
      last= string[-1]


      result = last+  mirror(middle) + first

      print (result)

    mirror(input("Type something please: "))
```

Comment: Your class should have mentioned something about base cases in recursion. Think about your base case.

Answer (score 2):

In order to work correctly, your function assumes that the input is at least two characters long.

At the same time, it calls itself recursively on a shortened version of the input — you need to consider when and how this chain of recursive calls needs to stop.

This aspect that you need to think about is called the [*base case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms).